# Main character wakes up as a woman's "toy" and is about to die, but discovers a game system which converts emotions into points for cultivation

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai, cultivation

Not 100% sure about isekai-transmigration; if the main character's personality was original, and he discovers a system, or if he's reincarnated in a dead body, reviving it and taking its place, but that also may be possible.

So, it's a cultivation fantasy world; the main character is living in a sect, but is used as toy for draining Qi from, by a woman using an evil cultivation technique. He was going to die soon, but discovers a game-like system, which converts any emotions directed at him into points. He can spend these points to learn and upgrade cultivation techniques, and does so on a very weak technique, which simply grows his life strength and helps him to survive the "draining". Due to this system, he starts to become very provocative to anyone (since he is protected by the same person who drains him as food, for being drained more), and gains more powers. He breaks into a sacred sect chamber, where a great woman was buried, and learns powerful techniques (from the system) for healing most wounds and restoring health, so his status grows.

Also, and most importantly, the system, with enough points, provides temporary transmigration into different worlds and different bodies, with different rules and main missions to complete, for gaining great rewards. One of them was quite similar to our modern world with technology, but also hidden cultivators and spirits.
I remember the story quite well, but can't find the manga (manhua) itself, so if anyone has questions about further details, you are welcome to ask.

Comment: Hi, welcome to the site. Is this full colour, or mostly black white? Also, did the main character have long hair or short hair, and what colour was their hair?

Comment: Hello! I believe... it was full color (or, at least, main chapter previews pages was colored), and black colored long hair, but he probably used hair comb, or braid hair, because i don't remember wearing him long hair behind back, probably bun hair style, or something.

Comment: Thanks for advice! Anyway, i would look it for myself as well, and if find it, gonna add comment about that, maybe someone else would be interested about that story.

Comment: Was the person draining the main character a woman?

Comment: Yes, she was, and she tried very hard to "drain last bit" of his life, but after some time passing, he survived, and she started to actually adore him more.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is ***[I'm an Evil God](https://www.mangaupdates.com/series.html?id=161917)***.

From Baka-Updates:

> Among the various realms, is the manliest and most handsome evil god in history! The peerless and handsome Xie Yan crosses over and falls into the vixen's lair. In order not to be drained of his entire life-force, he travels between various realms, cuts down a son of god, and repels an invading union hailing from across the ocean... This is the story of how he eventually becomes an evil god.

The main character starts out in the 'real' world as a young man named Xie Yan, and is run over by a truck. His soul then appears in a remote village in a fantasy version of Ancient China, and he sees another young man asleep in bed, whose face looks just like his.

His soul enters the body of that man, and he gains his memories. He recalls that this man has the same name as him, is the son of a government official, and the sexual plaything of a female martial artist named Qin Xinci, who's been draining his lifeforce night after night to increase her power. The man is barely alive at this stage.

He also discovers a game-like system which grants him 'origin points' when strong emotions are directed towards him. He then starts to deliberately anger people in the village to acquire points, and the first upgrade he buys slightly improves his physical fitness and vigour.

The game system also informs him that there are 'system fragments' scattered throughout the world, which he needs to find in order to unlock certain upgrades. In chapter 3, he breaks into an ancestral shrine to find one of these fragments, and touches the statue of a female sect-founder named Yu Xiuluo, which unlocks a 'realm travel' function, allowing him to travel to other worlds.

It turns out that when he travels to other worlds, his soul inhabits the bodies of alternate versions of himself. This is why the body he first took over had the same name and face as him. In chapter 17, he travels to a world named Qian Ming, which has more advanced technology, such as cars, guns, and cyborgs.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Im shaking. I looked for like total of 300 pages of my own comments and history at all manga sites i was sitting from like 2017, only to find that story, without any results. And here, within hour, it was found. Are you an cultivator, who ascended into heavens realm ? Because i have no other clues, how it was found that fast. Thank you, thank you, THANK YOU!